# send wordfile in email using mail() in php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I had send word document file in my mail when i send this document at that time it will generate unknown format like `asdfADFDF 0000sadfas15454454`

I had use mail function for sending mail .

Here is my code for that please check and let me know .

```
function sendfile()
{
    $id = $_REQUEST['id'];
    $s=mysql_query("select * from file_doc where id='".$id."'");
    $r= mysql_fetch_array($s);
    $r['email']; // user email address

    $docfile = "upload/".$r['cv']; // $r['cv'] is docfile



}
```

Comment: can u give me full details ?

Comment: If you have to ask, it's better that you don't even try. I suggest you install a proper mail library such as PHPMailer or Swift Mailer.

Comment: this is full detail of my function

Comment: RTFM, and you can read [mail php function doc](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.mail.php), [Swift mailer doc](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/introduction.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
if (isset($_FILES['uploaded_file']) &&
    $_FILES['uploaded_file']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    $mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'],
                         $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
}
```

Basic example can also be found here.

The function definition for AddAttachment is:

```
public function AddAttachment($path,
                              $name = '',
                              $encoding = 'base64',
                              $type = 'application/octet-stream')
```